# R splitting list into sublists by category

Tags: r, list

So I have some data like this..

| Q7 | ProblemGambling |
| --- | --- |
| 950 | 0 |
| 170 | 0 |
| 490 | 0 |
| 500 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 780 | 26 |
| 23.33 | 27 |
| 170 | 27 |
| 10 | 27 |

It is imported from an excel spreadsheet such that the first column contains a wide range of whole numbers, but the second column categorizes the corresponding values from the first in a range from 0 to 27. I need to first transform those second values into either "non-problem", "low-risk", "moderate-risk" or "problem", based on if they're 0, 1-4, 5-7, or 8+. Then I need to separate the resulting list into multiple sublists where each 2 of these categories pair off for further analysis.

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understood your problem but at least a partial solution should be this:

```
library(dplyr)

# some dummy data from your print 
df <- data.frame(Q7 = c(950, 170, 490, 500, 730, 23.33, 170, 10),
       ProblemGambling = c(0,0,0,0,26,27,27,27))

df %>% 
  # assing the groups acording to numeric range
  dplyr::mutate(ProblemGambling = case_when(ProblemGambling == 0 ~ "non-problem",
                                 ProblemGambling <= 4 ~ "low-risk",
                                 ProblemGambling <= 7 ~ "moderate-risk",
                                 TRUE ~ "problem")) %>% 
  # build groupings to be able to split by them
  dplyr::group_by(ProblemGambling) %>% 
  # split into sublist according to grouping
  dplyr::group_split()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Q7 ProblemGambling
  <dbl> <chr>          
1   950 non-problem    
2   170 non-problem    
3   490 non-problem    
4   500 non-problem    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Q7 ProblemGambling
  <dbl> <chr>          
1 730   problem        
2  23.3 problem        
3 170   problem        
4  10   problem
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `cut` with `split` in `base R`

```
split(df, cut(df$ProblemGambling, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 4, 7, Inf)), drop = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Q7 = c(950, 170, 490, 500, 730, 23.33, 170, 10),
   ProblemGambling = c(0,0,0,0,26,27,27,27))
```